# A class of finite groups with no element of order $\geq 8$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there infinitely many groups  $G$ of order $n=2^q\cdot3^r\cdot5^s\cdot7^t$, where at least two elements of $q,r,s,t$ are non-zero, and
with no element of order $d$ such that $d\geq 8$ or $d=6$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}_3$, thus it acts on $\mathbb{Z}^n_3$. If you take the semidirect product, then every element has order either $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Yes, you can choose any pair of $q,r,s,t$ to be nonzero and there are infinitely many such groups. They are all Frobenius groups. But it is not possible to have three of $q,r,s,t$ nonzero.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments and answer, M.H.?

Comment: Thanks all for your useful comments and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, I think, a realization, as a permutation group, of Levent's construction in the comments:

Consider the subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{3n}$ generated by the 3-cycles $(123),(456),(789),\dots$ and the involution $b=(12)(45)(78)\cdots$. This will have $3^n$ elements of order 2 (all looking a lot like $b$), $3^n-1$ elements of order 3 (products of the 3-cycles), and the identity.